# Why does setting tab bar controller's selectedViewController >= 4 throw error when there are more than 5 view controllers?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabBarController that I navigate programmatically. Calling the following method:

```
// UITabBarController subclass

- (void)tabForward
{
    NSUInteger selectedIndex = [self.viewControllers indexOfObject:self.selectedViewController];
    selectedIndex = selectedIndex + 1;
    if ( selectedIndex < [self.viewControllers count] )
        self.selectedViewController = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];
}
```

seems to work fine initially, but then this same line (`self.selectedViewController = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];`) throws the error, `[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil`, when there are more than 5 view controllers and selectedIndex == 4. However, if I just remove any of the view controllers from the tab bar controller to bring the total count to 5 view controllers or below, no error is thrown. This is driving me nuts. Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you add a snippet of code?

Comment: Hi yes, I just edited to show more. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// UITabBarController subclass

- (void)tabForward
{
    NSInteger selectedIndex = [self.viewControllers indexOfObject:self.selectedViewController];
    NSInteger nextIndex = selectedIndex + 1;
    if (nextIndex < self.viewControllers.count) {
        if (nextIndex > 3) { // use navigation controller when selectedIndex >= 4
            self.selectedViewController = self.moreNavigationController;
            [self.moreNavigationController pushViewController:self.viewControllers[nextIndex] animated:YES];
        } else {
            self.selectedViewController = self.viewControllers[nextIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was really going nuts! I feel like this idea should be a little more explicit in the UITabBarController documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your method with this one.

```
// UITabBarController subclass

- (void)tabForward
{
    NSUInteger selectedIndex = [self.viewControllers indexOfObject:self.selectedViewController];
    if (++selectedIndex < [self.viewControllers count]) {
        self.selectedViewController = [self.viewControllers objectAtIndex:selectedIndex];
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right that that's def a mistake, but that cannot be causing the error.

Comment: By checking `if (selectedIndex < [self.viewControllers count])`, you essentially determining whether or not an object exists at that index. However you already know `selectedIndex` exists, you need to check if `selectedIndex + 1` exists. Using ++selectedIndex updates the value of the the variable by one before it is considered in the if statements and can now be used to get objectAtIndex without adding one manually.

Comment: Right that's why the -1 was there. But that's not the issue here. The error and the circumstances of the error are unrelated to this.

Comment: The issue now is you are checking `selectedIndex < [self.viewControllers count]`, this tells you whether or not `selectedIndex` is a valid index. Then you're getting `objectAtIndex: selectedIndex + 1` but you haven't checked whether or not that index is less than the count.

Comment: By checking if `selectedIndex < [self.viewControllers count] - 1`, I effectively am checking if selectedIndex + 1 is a valid index. But I just edited to make it more explicit.

Comment: Yep, I just realised that they are infact the same thing